# What to watch out for when using lithium grease?

Tags: lubrication

I've only used machine oil compounds for lubrication previously, lithium grease is new to me. What do I watch out for?

I mean when using machine oil and similar stuff it should not be applied to plastic because many plastics get dissolved this way. Also machine oil will stain porous materials and those stains are nearly impossible to remove. Other than that machine oil is more or less fool proof - can be applied to any metal, doesn't damage it.

What are similar guidelines for lithium grease?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_grease) mentions nothing of what you are worried about, and I have never heard of it having an issue staining or dissolving anything.  I've used it on many things including plastics, and never personally had any issue.  I know it is used on the plastic moving parts inside things like VCRs and DVD players, and I know it is used on many different types of metal machinery as well.